# Find spanning tree using bfs in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to find a spanning tree in a graph using igraph function `graph.bfs`.
Could you show me how?

PS: I try to use the `$father` info of the returned value from `graph.bfs`, but the result confuses me. Here is an example:

```
g <- graph(c(1,2,2,6,1,4,4,6,5,6,1,5,5,3,3,4), directed=FALSE)
plot(g)

tmp <- graph.bfs(g, root=1, neimode='all', order=TRUE, father=TRUE,callback=f)
```

[image: find spanning tree]

The result is :
`tmp$order = 1 2 4 5 6 3` and `tmp$father=0 1 4 1 1 2`

Can I use the `$father` info to find all the spanning tree?

Comment: Why not just using `minimum.spanning.tree()`?

Comment: I just want to try out different methods to find spanning trees,not just minimum spanning trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `father` vector is indexed by the nodes, i.e., it is not in the same order as `order`.

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph(c(1,2,2,6,1,4,4,6,5,6,1,5,5,3,3,4), directed=FALSE)
r <- graph.bfs(g, root=1, neimode='all', order=TRUE, father=TRUE)
h <- graph( rbind(r$order, r$father[r$order])[,-1], directed=FALSE )
plot(h)
```

In this example, we have:

```
order:  1 2 4 5 6 3
father: 0 1 4 1 1 2.
```

The `i`th element of `order` is the name (or index) of `i`th node in the pre-traversal order.

The `i`th element of `father` is the name (or index) of the parent of the node with index `i` -- not of the `i`th element of `order`. The parent of the `i`th element of `order` is `parent[order[i]]`. This is what we need to define the edges.

The edges of the tree are therefore:

```
order:  1 2 4 5 6 3
        | | | | | |
father: 0 1 1 1 2 4.
```

Comment: Looks correct. But could you please explain "The father vector is indexed by the nodes"? I don't get it. Thanks!

Comment: I have attempted to add a few explanations.

Comment: I think I understand. But is it a bad design? If you don't have `$order`, so `$father` becomes useless.

Comment: It is not a bad design. You need either `order` and `father`, or `order` and `father[order]`, and you can easily switch from one representation to another. Building the tree turns out to be more straightforward with the latter representation.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid errors like: 
Error in simple_vs_index(x, ii, na_ok) : Unknown vertex selected
we need to change one of code statements as:

```
h <- graph( rbind(r$order, r$father[r$order, na_ok = TRUE])[,-1], directed=FALSE )
```

This allows for NA to be present in indices.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `order` is straightforward. For `father`,

```
> r$order
6/6 vertices, from 29ab0f7:
[1] 1 2 4 5 6 3
> r$father
+ 6/6 vertices, from 29ab0f7:
[1] NA  1  4  1  1  2
```

- node 1 (node with label 1) does not have a father -->NA
- node 2 has node 1 as a father
- node 3 has node 4 as a father
- node 4 has node 1 as a father
- node 5 has node 1 as a father
- node 6 has node 2 as a father*

There is easy confusion here in cases denoted by the asterisk.
"Why is node 6 fathered by node 2 but not node 4?". The answer is that the father is not defined as the most recent element in the transversal sequence that node 6 is connected to, but the earliest element in the transversal sequence that node 6 is connected to. i.e. node 6 is connected to node 2 and node 4 (node 2 is earlier in the transversal sequence). Here is an example that makes this concept obvious

```
g <- sample_smallworld(1, 5, 5, 0.05)
plot(g)
r <- graph.bfs(g, root=1, neimode='all', order=TRUE, father=TRUE)
```

[image]

As you can see, node 1 fathers all the nodes because it is the earliest in the transversal sequence and it is connected to all the nodes.

```
$order
+ 5/5 vertices, from 0960d64:
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$father
+ 5/5 vertices, from 0960d64:
[1] NA  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer given by "Vincent Zoonekynd" above. However, it did not work as-it-is with me. So I made some modifications in order for it to work. Here is my code

```
library(igraph)
g2 <- graph(c(1,2,2,6,1,4,4,6,5,6,1,5,5,3,3,4), directed=FALSE)
r <- graph.bfs(g2, root=1, neimode='all', order=TRUE, father=TRUE)
a = as.integer(r$order)
aa = as.integer(r$father)
h <- graph( rbind(a, aa[a])[,-1], directed=FALSE )
plot(h)
```

It give a new matrix "h", which is based on the minimum spanning tree of original graph